# Как ускорить время ответа на запрос?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, big-data, mongodb-query

Существует коллекция в базе, которая насчитывается около 4.6 миллиона документов.
(структуру данных можно увидеть на скриншоте.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке вытащить из данной коллекции хотя бы одно значение - время ответа на запрос достигает более 3 секунд:
(и это на моей локальной довольно мощной машине.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код работы с запросом выглядит следующим образом:

```
    // server.js
    const http = require('http');
    const { getProducts } = require('./controllers/currencyController');
    
    const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        if(req.url.match(/\/api\/currency.+/g) && req.method === 'GET') {
            getProducts(req, res);
        } else {
            res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
            res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Route Not Found' }))
        }
    })
    
    const PORT =  process.env.PORT || 5000
    server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
    module.exports = server;


    //  currencyModel.js
    const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
    const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/');
    
    const findAll = async (currencyPair) => {
        try{
            await client.connect();
            const testingData = client.db('Trading').collection(currencyPair);
            return testingData;
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    module.exports = {
        findAll,
    }


// currencyController.js
const currencyData = require('../models/currencyModel')

async function getProducts(req, res) {
    try {
        const currency_data = await currencyData.findAll('EUR/USD');
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        res.end(JSON.stringify(await currency_data.find({id:1}).toArray()));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getProducts,
}
```

Подозреваю что причина такого долгого ответа может быть как то связано с отсутствием индексов.
(те числовые, что присутствуют сейчас созданы кастомно.)

Вопрос:
Каким образом можно ускорить время получения ответа от сервера после получения запроса?
(желательно без применения ORM и фреймворков.)
И каким вообще должно быть это время в идеале?

Comment: Может стоит тащить из монго только нужные данные а не все подряд?))

Comment: я не против - но каким конкретно образом? )

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/321104/

Comment: Не совсем понял - какое конкретно решение прописать необходимо.
Тут используется в статье экспресс и часть кода юзается только для монги до версии 2.3

Comment: Это вам должно быть видней что именно использовать вместо ```currencyData.findAll('EUR/USD')``` для получения того что вам надо, как работать с фильтрами в статье описано :)

Comment: Так вы не поняли.
FindAll - это функция с другого модуля - это не метод для взятия данных из колекции.
(в коде же я указал в коментах из какого модуля какой код.)

Comment: Вы разобрались?

Comment: а вы пробовали создать индекс для того ключа который вы чаще всего используете?

Comment: еще нет - писал об этом в данном посте.

Comment: эту бд можно где-то скачать в виде дампа?

Comment: к сожалению нет.